# Load a method from another assembly using Mono.Cecil

Tags: c#, .net, cil, mono.cecil

My code uses Mono.Cecil to rewrite IL code of an assembly. I need to import a method that belongs to another assembly which is provided as a reference. Therefore it is throwing error in the Assembly.write method.

Method is defined in another module and needs to be imported.

I need to import whole class from another assembly into the main module.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Could you provide the error message?

Comment: XXXMethod is defined in another module and needs to be imported.